# How do i add attribute to html tag with jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a html page with `<html>` tag where I want to add `dir="rtl"` and `lang="ar"` attributes using jQuery when user click on arabic language in drop-down.

I tried using `$(html).attr("dir","rtl")`

But it returns undefined. Can somebody help as I'm new to jQuery

Comment: Please include the exact code you've used, ideally in a stack snippet (edit and click `[<>]`) including a `<script>` for jquery.

Comment: It's unclear where/how you've tried the `.attr` code or where/how you're determining that it "returns" undefined.   Do you have any errors in the console?

Comment: Typo?  Unless you've defined a variable called `html` somewhere, it looks like you just forgot quotes around the selector: `$("html").attr("dir","rtl")`  (If you haven't defined that variable, surely the browser's development console is telling you that...)

Comment: Yeah infact i just wanted to check if i can use the mentioned snippet of jQuery to add dir attribute ..in console it returned undefined

Comment: Wo wo wo im sorry..thats  a typo... @David your solution worked .. thanks for saving !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an error on your code, the "html" tag should be written with quotes as folows:

```
$('html').attr("dir","rtl")
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: Ok, closed]

Ok, the question is closed, answer given, so no use for this answer anymore.

Comment: And this a close vote...